# Conditional value replacement in linked column

Tags: r

In a data frame, I want to replace a value based on a condition in another column.

Example: when the value in column A is above x, then both values in column A and B are replaced by NA.

I can't find the proper way to do this with the different functions: `na_if`, `ifelse`, `if_else`,`case_when`...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a working answer:

```
d <- data.frame("A" = 1:10, "B" = 11:20)

x <- 5

d[d$A > x, c("A", "B")] <- NA
```

Comment: Great! Thanks a lot! Any idea why this doesn't work when column A already contains some NA? And how to still make this work?

Comment: d[d$A > x & !is.na(d$A), c("A", "B")] <- NA

Answer (score 1):

Subscript the data frame by a logical vector having the condition:

```
DF[DF$A > x, c("A", "B")] <- NA
```